# PYTHON Catch function output

Tags: python, function, output, try-catch

```
from GmailChecker import GmailChecker

def Checker():
 Email = 'myemailemailemaul@gmail.com'
 Checker = GmailChecker.verify(Email,1)
 try:
  if 'Unregistered' in Checker:
   print ('False')
  else:
   print ('Alive')
 except:
  print('Error occurred')
  
  
Checker()
```

this function is forcing output myemailemailemaul@gmail.com Unregistered
i can't catch the output may some help

tried to catch the output if 'Unregistered' in Checker:
with no hope it gives Error occurred as exception

Comment: Don't `print`, `return`

Comment: Side note: _Please_ follow PEP 8 and use four spaces for indentation. Single-space indentation is very hard to read, and in an indentation-sensitive language like Python it's _insane_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, `Checker = GmailChecker.verify(Email,1)` is a NoneType object and always returns none. You can `print(Checker)` to verify this. It is not an iterable therefore this code `if 'Unregistered' in Checker` fails. I'm not sure why you included a try-except block in your code but I'm guessing it's because of the errors raised by this code.

If you just want your function to show whether a gmail account is alive or unregistered, use the refactored version of your codes below:

```
from GmailChecker import GmailChecker

def gmail_checker():
    email = 'myemailemailemaul@gmail.com'
    checker = GmailChecker.verify(email, 1)
    return f"Finished checking {email}."
  
  
print(gmail_checker())
```

Output:

```
myemailemailemaul@gmail.com Unregistered
Finished checking myemailemailemaul@gmail.com.
```

Please note that this program is a Gmail validity checker and will return only two results:

- Alive: means that everything is fine with this Gmail and is being used.
- Unregistered: It means that the Gmail is not registered or is blocked.
  See https://pypi.org/project/GmailChecker/ for more details.

Comment: is there anyway to catch the output to using it in another function ?

Comment: A NoneType Object returns none. Except you want to catch the output 'none', which I doubt.